# User Application issues with SQLLocalDB

Tags: sql-server

I've been working to resolve an issue with SQLLocalDB and one of our applications.

The application runs in our Citrix environment which users log into using roaming profiles.

The issue can be outlined as follows: A user accesses the software for the first time with no issue.  A Database directory (with an .mdf and .ldf) in (\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0) created by the application is stored in the users roaming profile, but also the SQLLocalDB is created in the users local profile on the server.  The issue occurs when the user logs out:  the users roaming profile is loaded back to the file server.  When the user logs in the files are pulled back down to the terminal server and a discrepancy is created between the application and the database.

If I clear the database files created in the users roaming profile and run the following commands:
sqllocaldb delete v11.0
sqllocaldb create v11.0

This will allow the application to run again, although I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this discrepancy.

I believe the issue is with how the application reads these files but if anyone can help shed some light on this issue.  I can provide more information as necessary.

Thanks!